# Skip the intro in Brothers

Tags: brothers-tale-of-two-sons

I have already played Brothers once but I don't have all achievements.

I'd like to play again, but skip the intro. Is there a way? I pressed all buttons, but nothing seems to skip it.

Comment: There is a chapter select on the title/play screen. Does this let you skip forward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the posts [here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/225080/discussions/0/540741859214937559/)

> I finished the game. Why can I still not skip cutscenes?

and [here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/225080/discussions/0/648813727967533288/)

> Skip Cutscene would be nice..

it doesn't look like skipping cutscenes is possible.